# Simple code to place an image on a coordinate

Tags: html

I want to place an image at a fixed coordinate on the page, left corner of screen for example.
I also want to control the size of the image.

Comment: error corrected. Why do i want to do this ? 
I want an image on left and text on right side of that image, that is a partition. So i guessed that i will put image somewhere near left corner and text just beside it. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample that positions an image. Coordinates are specified using field 'margin' of the img tag.  You can change the size of the image by varying width and height.  Copy and save the snippet below (use extension html), and open it in any browser to see it in action.

```
<img src="http://fanumusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Free.jpg" style="float:right;    margin:0px 0px 15px 15px; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; border:0" width="100" height="100" alt="sample image" />
```

Here's a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) to page that details the various html tag options.